# How do we prove (in metric spaces) that $f(x)\to L$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$ iff $f(a_n)\to L$ whenever $a_n$ approaches $x_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(X,d_{X})$ and $(Y,d_{Y})$ be metric spaces, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. Let $x_{0}\in X$ be an adherent point of $E$ and $L\in Y$. Then the following statements are logically equivalent:

(a) $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0};x\in E}f(x) = L$

(b) For every sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $E$ which converges to $x_{0}$ with respect to the metric $d_{X}$, the sequence $(f(x_{n}))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $L$ with respect to the metric $d_{Y}$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let us prove the implication $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$ first.

According to the definition of limit, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x\in E$ one has that
\begin{align*}
d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f(x),L) < \varepsilon 
\end{align*}

Consequently, if $x_{n}\to x_{0}$, for every $\delta > 0$, there is a natural number $N\geq 1$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Rightarrow d_{X}(x_{n},x_{0}) < \delta
\end{align*}

Given that $x_{n}\in E$ for every $n\geq N$, we can substitute $x$ by $x_{n}$, whence we conclude that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N\geq 1$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Rightarrow d_{X}(x_{n},x) < \delta \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f(x_{n}),L) < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

and $f(x_{n})\to L$.

Conversely, let us prove that $(b)\Rightarrow(a)$.

Let us suppose that $(b)$ holds, but $(a)$ does not.

Consequently, there is a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ there is a $x\in E$ which satisfy
\begin{align*}
d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta\quad\wedge\quad d_{Y}(f(x),L)\geq\varepsilon
\end{align*}
Thus for every $\delta = 1/n$ corresponds a $x_{n}\in E$ satisfying $d_{X}(x_{n},x_{0}) < 1/n$. Taking the limit, one concludes that $x_{n}\to x_{0}$.

On the other hand, $f(x_{n})\not\rightarrow L$, which contradicts our assumption.

Hence the proposed result holds.

Comment: Can you say what is the definition of an adherent point?

Comment: We say that $x_{0}\in X$ is an adherent point of $E$ iff every open ball $B(x_{0},r)$ centered at $x_{0}$ with positive radius $r > 0$ intersects $E$ in at least one point.

Comment: Okay. It is same as saying that $x$ is in the closure of $E$ , and I think you already have a proof.